# Is it allowed to indulge in sex daily during winters?

Tags: sex, ayurveda

Previously I used to think that it is mandatory to not participate in sex during some days like the full moon, new moon, Ashtami, Ekadasi, chaturdasi, festivals, etc.,

Recently I came across the following statement from an Ayurvedic scripture [1](https://www.easyayurveda.com/2013/03/12/ashtanga-hrudayam-sutrasthana-7th-chapter/)

> During Hemanta and shishira (winter) the person can indulge in
> copulation (**daily) as much as he likes** after making use of
> aphrodisiacs (and obtaining strength)

I know that scriptures are not stubborn to apply the same rule for all times, so the above may be a valid one since it is also written by a Maharshi.

But I am wondering whether there is any other scripture that allows involvement in sex at all days during winter.